# Convert list of tuples in tabular format in python

Tags: python, pandas

What is an elegant way to convert a list of tuples into tables in  the following form?

Input:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
mytup = [('a','b',1), ('a','c',2), ('b','a',2), ('c','a',3), ('c','c',1)]

a       b       1
a       c       2
b       a       2
c       a       3
c       c       1

mydf = DataFrame(mytup, columns = ['from', 'to', 'val'])
```

output: `-` may be replaced with blank or `nan`

```
     a    b    c
a    -    1   2
b    2    -   -
c    3    -   1
```

Comment: ```str.format()``` is your new best friend

Comment: @wnnmaw, The tables are different. I modified the OP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pivot` and `fillna` are what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

mytup = [('a','b',1), ('a','c',2), ('b','a',2), ('c','a',3), ('c','c',1)]
mydf = pd.DataFrame(mytup, columns=['from', 'to', 'val'])
mydf.pivot(index='from', columns='to', values='val').fillna(value='-')

to    a  b  c
from         
a     -  1  2
b     2  -  -
c     3  -  1
```

Comment: thanks. I was trying the `pivot` thing but somehow couldnt find the suitable example. Thanks again

Comment: @learner, glad it helps :) you may read more about `pivot` [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).

Comment: as a side note, if you don't mind showing `NaN`, you can simply omit `fillna(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm wrong and there's a more direct way to do this, but if not, you can always loop over the tuples:

```
>>> df = DataFrame([['-'] * 3]*3, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> for row, col, val in mytup:
...     df[col][row] = val
>>> df
   a  b  c
a  -  1  2
b  2  -  -
c  3  -  1
```

---

If you were just dealing with numpy/scipy rather than pandas, I'd note that your tuple format is pretty close to the [COO sparse matrix format](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix), so:

```
>>> tup = [(ord(x)-ord('a'), ord(y)-ord('a'), z) for x,y,z in mytup]
>>> x, y, values = zip(*tup)
>>> m = np.array(scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((values, (x, y))).todense())
>>> print(m)
[[0 1 2]
 [2 0 0]
 [3 0 1]]
```

However, I don't think pandas has the equivalent of "sparse data frames", and I don't know that it would be more "elegant" to convert to a raw array just to build the resulty array to convert back to a data frame. (It might be more efficient if you could do the letter-to-number mapping vectorized, but that likely doesn't matter here.)